# I want to add some variation to the colours of my sprites in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to add some variation to the colour of each sprite using the following code:

```
spriterenderer.color = colour+ new Color32(Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(-10,10)), Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(-10, 10)), Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(-10, 10)),255);
```

This did not work, what way should I do this?

Comment: color always >= 0 , and it's range is 0~1 ,
if you want to use byte to rgb , you need cast it to Color32

Comment: What's the result you got? What's the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: derHugo solved the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html) always has components that are clamped to `0 - 255`. You will never get negative values anyway.

Additionally you are using `Convert.ToByte`. A `byte` itself already can not be negative either and for negative values you will get a

> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.

You should rather go component wise and do something like e.g.

```
// Implicit conversion Color -> Color32
Color32 temp = colour;

// This makes sure the value never goes under 0 or beyond 255
temp.r = (byte) Mathf.Clamp(temp.r + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-10, 11), byte.MinValue, byte.MaxValue);
temp.g = (byte) Mathf.Clamp(temp.g + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-10, 11), byte.MinValue, byte.MaxValue);
temp.b = (byte) Mathf.Clamp(temp.b + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-10, 11), byte.MinValue, byte.MaxValue);

spriterenderer.color = temp;
```

Comment: @GeorgeBland now it should work ^^ I did a lot of unnecessary stuff there (writing on the phone ^^)

Comment: Works like a charm!